# Remove rows from a CSV file when a 4 columns have null values

Tags: unix, csv, sed

I have a CSV file and I need to filter out some rows that do not contain certain values. Because of this I don't care about those rows and want to remove them or put the results of the command in a new csv file.

This is the format of my CSV file:

```
employeeid,time,homephone,workphone,ssn,insurance,address,state,salary,position,rank,boss,hiredate
```

Now there are some rows that have no information some of these fields. How would I perform an awk or sec command to read all the lines in the csv file and only put the lines which no fields are null into another file? Or would it be possible to replace every `,,` with a word like `notthere`? I have some word replacing going on here but this is not 100% working.

So far I have something like this:

```
sed -e 's/^,/notthere,/' old.csv > new.csv
```

This pretty much does nothing that I am looking for. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out. I am not that experienced with using linux commands at all.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you could also grep the file for connected commas:

```
grep -v ',,' somefile.csv > newfile.csv
```

**EDIT:** Just realized you have fields at the beginning and end you want to check for as well. We can include those with regex, like so:

```
grep -vE ',,|^,|,$' somefile.csv > newfile.csv
```

`grep -v` means 'inverse', in other words: print all lines that don't match these patterns: two commas together, a comma at the start of the line, a comma at the end of the line.  The `|` here means "or".

Comment: Thank you so much! The inverse way of doing things is interesting and works at the same time. Now I can carry on with my other code I need to do. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I actually use `grep -v` and `grep -vE` all the time.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
sed -e 's/,,/,notthere,/' old.csv > new.csv
```

Comment: should add `-e 's/^,/notthere,/' -e 's/,$/,notthere/'` to check first and last field for emptiness

Answer (score 0):

Some sample data would have helped, but try this to skip lines with empty fields:

```
awk -F , '{n=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="") n++} n==0' filename
```

More readably

```
awk -F , '{
    empty=0
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i == "") {
            empty++
        }
    }
    if (empty == 0) {
        print
    }
}' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that the above examples are "grepping" across the entire row. Another approach is to search specific columns for non-existence using awk as shown below. Given a comma delimited file, the below script only prints lines that have empty values in column 2 signified by `$2`. The `print $0` portion means print the entire line.

Print all lines where column 2 is empty, redirect to new.csv

```
awk -F "," '$2 !~ /./ {print $0}' old.csv > new.csv
```

Another related example, print column 3 when only it matches regular expression `[0-9]`

```
awk -F "," '$3 ~ /[0-9]/ {print $3}' old.csv > new.csv
```